# Choreography saga

Tags: microservices, distributed-transactions

I have applied the DB-Per-Service pattern.
2PC is forbidden.

Does choreography saga with each service locking its edited resource is considered a bad practice ?
I have to atomically update 3 services.
So i use saga that updates atomically each service,changes version number of record to avoid concurrency issue, then proceeds to next service.
When something fails i rollback service by service with a message queue.

Isn’t it basically an async implementation of 2pc with the disadvantage of user reading precommited data that could be rolled back? Do i have to lock the resources processed so i can rollback with out data loses?

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, your saga is basically an async 2pc, though it's arguably not atomic since uncommitted values could be read.

That said, if there's an actual business need (there most often isn't) for strong consistency between pieces of data, that's a pretty good sign that all of that data wants to be owned by the same service (i.e. the service boundaries don't fit the business requirements).  This is where defining services based on the tables in a relational schema tends to fall apart, in my experience.